# How to use 'Salt' for spark repartitioning while writing data

Tags: apache-spark

[image: task visialization1[![task visialization2]Recently I faced a data scew while writing data, I am writing data with repartitioning based on year , month , week as follows-

```
df.repartition(col("year"),col("month"),col("week"))        
.write.csv(".........")
```

one of the task took longer and never finished, whereas other were finished successfully within minutes because there was less data to process.

Can you please guide on how can I use salt key for repartitioning along with year month and week field.

Comment: Can yous how us the distribution of data? "because there was more data for some of the weeks" is hard to follow as a reasoning. Seems like you are saying the more data the quicker - or am I missing something?

Comment: thank you @thebluephantom, it really helps to understand the question now. I just edited with the visual image.

Comment: Indeed, skew data, but surprising for temporal aspects. English can be a little clearer still, imho.

Comment: @thebluephantom can you tell me which part is hard to understand and unclear, I would happy to be clear on that, As I am stuck on this and seeking some help/guidance on solution

Comment: I think some of the parts finished due to the fact that there was less data to process would be more precise?

Answer (score 1):

In case you're still interested:

You could create a random column (e.g. `.withColumn("salt", (rand * 1000).cast(IntegerType))`) but from what the ui shows, it looks like it'd worth it taking a deeper look into your current data as well.

There are chances that a big percentage of your data contains some default (if not null) value (e.g. 1/1/70) which you use to create the year, month, week columns.